# How to type text with only one tap in iOS Accessibility

Tags: ios, objective-c

This may look weird but I need to know this. I am handling VoiceOver for an iOS app and I have done almost with everything for custom UIs too.

What I am worried is while typing in a textfield, I need to first select the letter by single tap and then need to double tap to activate it. Is that only process which Apple is providing? Or is there any other way where I can type as I tap a letter/digit?

I checked in the setting too if there is any way but couldn't find. I tried with Android's accessibility and it works with only single tap.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Remember the users who use accessibility know how it works, so don't tamper with it...

Comment: Thanks Wain! So you mean we are not supposed to do any coding for this?

Comment: No, image you're partially sighted, if something doesn't work in the way you expect then you're lost.